# Non Autolayout code with Autolayout enabled doesn't break constraints

Tags: ios, autolayout

I just implemented a `Non Autolayout Code` to use `UIPanGestureRecognizer` on my Autolayout enabled view with Autolayout constraints added on the components. What I mean by Non Autolayout Code is I am not updating or, changing any constraints in my code..

**See my code below**

```
- (IBAction)panJoystick:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)gesture {
    CGPoint translation = [gesture translationInView:self.controlsView];

    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

        lastCentre=self.joystickView.center;

    }else{
        self.joystickView.center=CGPointMake(lastCentre.x+translation.x, lastCentre.y+ translation.y);
    }

}
```

You can see I am not using any constraints in the code, and not changing any constant. The code above works absolutely fine without producing any `Autolayout Warning`. HOW?

My question is why it is not giving me any Autolayout warning runtime, as I am changing the position of the Joystick without updating the Autolayout constraints..

I am confused. Can any one help?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think changing the frame should produce an error... only if you have conflicting constraints the system should show you an error...
and I think the code is working because it continuously changing the frame.. if you will try the change the frame only once and let it be I think it will go back to it's original position..

Comment: @Blacky I am confused because, in design time, if I set any constraint to any component and change the frame it generates constraint warning, but in runtime it doesn't. And too after changing frame it never comes back to original position as you are saying..

Comment: There is no need to be confused, in IB it's only a warning that on runtime the screen will look different than what you see on IB.
However when you see "Warning" in console its not a warning it's an Error!
Because you have conflicts in your constrains, but the system tried to fix them.
I hope I was clear...